# add text message to wowza live stream video broadcasting in android

Tags: android, live-streaming, wowza

I am using wowza gocoder sdk and wowza stream engine to live broadcast video. Now I want to enable user to comment on broadcasters video. I don't understand the procedure, where I should start. how can I synchronize the text message to the video. Do I need to implement it separately or wowza provide something to live stream the text as well. I will be grateful for any guidence because I have searched everywhere possible but no one give precise answer or solution

Comment: Does this streaming engine have a `DataChannel`? Its better if you read their Documentation. On first search i found [This](https://www.wowza.com/community/questions/42225/datachannel-can-not-be-used-with-wowza-webrtc.html) . They have a forum you can also ask question directly on Forum .

Comment: @ADM I have sent request to the forum. If not supported by them, can you tell me any other api that support live video broadcasting along with the text chat?